RTL8152 not working for mobile devices
We are using iOS devices for the user interface on our machines. To sent data between our board and the iOS device we are using ethernet. Right now we are using dongles with ethernet. But this means we need to route a USB-C cable and ethernet cable. These dongles often have short cables and take up a lot of room. Since almost all devices support USB-C we are trying to implement these dongles on our boards. All of them are based on RTL8153 or RTL8152. We decided to use the RTL8152. Along with the TPS25820 (or TPS25821) for USB C 1.3 PD we want to power and setup a ethernet connection over the single USB-C cable.
I'm struggling for some time with the following issue... The PCB works with a Windows computer and shows up as a FE Ethernet connection. However on any mobile device (Android phone, iPhone or iPad) it does not work. Based on the schematic is there anything simple I'm missing to support mobile devices?
I've verified with the Windows PC that we have a working ethernet connection, and that the RTL8152 can work. I'm mainly worried about the board/pcb not showing itself correctly to a mobile device. My hunch says that something is wrong with how the board handles power delivery and the mobile devices wil not even try to initialize the ethernet connection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In the end the PD chip TPS25821/20 does not support data role swap, which can be achieved with a ONSEMI FUSB302. This was the reason for the problems.
